# How would you output count()?

Tags: mysql, sql

can someone please tell me how you would output this? Output it like Location M F Total.

```
   SELECT location, SUM(IF(gender='M',1,0)) AS M,
    SUM(IF(gender='F',1,0)) AS F, COUNT(*) AS total
    GROUP by location;
```

Taken from - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/page3.html

Thanks

EDIT

How to get answers like

```
location    M   F   total
Boston          1   2       3
Cagliari    1   2   3
London          1   1   2
Manchester  1   1   2
Marseille   1   2   3
Milano          2   0   2
New York    2   2   4
Paris           1   1   2
Roma            3   0   3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how would you output it"?

Comment: SQL is not a programming language, it is a query language. Why are you trying to format tings in the SQL??

Comment: i was refering from the link given........

Comment: I would encourage closers to try and comment question improvement suggestions before voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop through it and echo it into a table:

```
<?php 
    $q="SELECT location, SUM(IF(gender='M',1,0)) AS M,
    SUM(IF(gender='F',1,0)) AS F, COUNT(*) AS total
    GROUP by location";
    $query=mysql_query($q);
    echo '<table>';
    while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$r['location'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$r['M'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$r['F'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$r['total'].'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: ah I see I was trying something like echo $M, $F etc..... Thanks, ill try that

Comment: if my answer works, can you please select it as the answer and give it an up arrow?

Comment: is it possible to put it in a for loop? Its only showing the first row?

Comment: the `while` part is the loop, so long as there are more rows in the query, `$r` gets a new rows each loop, a `while` loop is much more appropriate than a `for` loop, however, theoretically you could use either